# Aspect-level entity extraction and sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, data-science, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-extraction

I am working on Natural Language Processing and having a hard time on analyzing sentiment values on certain entities. For example if i say: "I love the fact that I am finally leaving Chicago", it says that the sentence is a positive sentence. But as you can see it is pretty negative for the entity "Chicago". Anyone knows if there is any related work on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The key word for this is “targeted sentiment analysis”

There are many articles on it and also code on GitHub.

I’ll update if I find the link for the model I used.

You might need to do some labeling and training for your specific requirements.

Update:
https://github.com/songyouwei/ABSA-PyTorch

train data will look like this:

```
I love the fact that I am finally leaving $T$, Chicago, -1
```